# Xcode 3.2.4 - how to break a line in multiple ones

Tags: iphone, xcode

Part of my code will output HTML code to a file. I have a header that will be stamped in the beginning of all files. I would like to declare it as:

```
NSString *myHeader = @"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\"\n
  \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\">\n
\n
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" xml:lang=\"en\" lang=\"en\">\n
  <head>\n
    <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html;charset=UTF-8\" />\n
    <meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"chrome=1\">\n
        <title>My Title</title>\n
    <link rel=\"search\" type=\"application/opensearchdescription+xml\" href=\"/opensearch.xml\" title=\"GitHub\" />\n
    <link rel=\"fluid\" href=\"http://mysite.com/fluid.png\" title=\"fluid\" />\n
";
```

Obviously I have escaped the quotes, but even doing that, Xcode is not liking this string declaration spread on several lines. If possible I would like to keep it that way, instead of joining it on a long line that would be difficult to read and change.

How can I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this:

```
NSString *myHeader = @"text here"
  @"more text here"
  @"even more text here"
  @"still more text";
```

Comment: Man, you are a genius!!!!! I would never imagined that in a thousand years... I know your nick says it is obvious, but not to me! Thanks!!!!

Comment: Thanks, the name is just a joke and no reflection on the questioner.

Answer (score 3):

This works in Xcode:

```
const char *val = "Hello world"
                  "this is me";
```